# Array of underscore

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

So in this code, I'm trying to insert `_` to an array but I don't really know what's wrong with this code. Because it seems to get stucked when the `_` is being inserted to the array. Is there better way to implement or fix the code?

```
.data
strUnderscore BYTE 20 DUP (?)             ;the array
.code
mov ECX,stringLength 
mov ESI, OFFSET strUnderscore 
L1: 
mov strUnderscore[ESI], '_'            ;the code runs but stucks here
inc ESI 
loop L1

mov EDX, OFFSET strUnderscore 
call WriteString
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the loop starts, ESI already points at strUnderscore, because you intialize it that way. Meanwhile, the line

```
mov strUnderscore[ESI], '_'
```

tries to write a character to address strUnderscore + ESI. That's not right. In C-like terms, what you have now is:

```c
char *esi = strUnderscore;
while(...)
{
    strUnderscore[(int)esi] = '_';
    esi++;
}
```

You want either a running index, or a running pointer. Either initialize ESI to 0 (and it will be used as an index), or change the destination address in the `mov` command to `byte ptr [ESI]`.

Also, LOOP is a bad command (look it up). Consider a decrement and a conditional jump instead.

Comment: The OP is still learning the very basics. Let her debug a loop.

Comment: When I changed the destination address command in the mov to [ESI], the program couldn't run. It says invalid instruction operands on that line. Do you know what's the cause?

Comment: The operand size is not obvious - the assembler doesn't know whether you're writing a byte or a dword with the numeric value '_'. Change to `mov byte ptr [esi], '_'`

Answer (score 1):

Two errors in your code :

- ESI is a pointer, not an index.
- The compiler doesn't know the size of "_".

Let's fix them :

```
.data
strUnderscore BYTE 20 DUP (?)             ;the array
.code
mov ECX,stringLength 
mov ESI, OFFSET strUnderscore  ;◄■■ ESI IS POINTER TO THE VARIABLE.
mov AL, '_'                    ;◄■■ MOVE THE "_" INTO A ONE BYTE REGISTER.
L1: 
mov [ESI], AL                  ;◄■■ USE THE POINTER ESI, THE VARIABLE IS NOT NECESSARY.
inc ESI 
loop L1

mov EDX, OFFSET strUnderscore 
call WriteString
```

Comment: and as the `al` doesn't change during the whole loop, the `mov al, '_'` can be ahead of `L1:`. :)